# Error while trying to run project. The address is not valid for this context

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have 64x console application in VS 2013. When I've tried to run x64 application in debug mode, I've got a message:

```
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program [PathToMyApplication].
The address is not valid for this context.
```

For 32x application it worsk fine. Reinstall VS 2013 did't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in sniffer software "SearchInformAgent".

Answer (score 2):

My error message is similar when starting the project:

"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'C:\Project\StrictAny\PrensentationLayer\bin\PPEREM.exe'

The address is not valid for this context "

I solved the problem by switching [Solution Explorer=>Solution Properties=>Active config=>Debug|AnyCUP] to "Debug|x86"

Then the application proceeds in starting.

hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Yes, it helps, but if you need 64x mode it is useless

Comment: I came across this error 1 year after and I realize the answer which worked was replied by me, it seems I helped myself. lol

Comment: This helped me to solve error & able to run console app. Thanks @Richard